# Best memory practices and optimizations for Solidity gas fees

Tags: optimization, memory, ethereum, solidity

I have a state variable in my smart contract called "_ownerAddresses". It is an array of addresses. In one of my functions, I remove addresses from this array depending on a condition. I was wondering what is the best approach to doing this in a fast and memory-efficient way. Should I delete addresses while in the for loop and shrink the array? Should I create a new storage array that just adds the addresses I am keeping and then assign "_ownerAddresses" to this new array? Here is the excerpt of code:

```
struct Sub {
        uint256 amount;
        uint256 createdTime;
}

mapping(address => Sub) private _addrBalances;
address[] private _ownerAddresses;
uint MONTH = 30 days;
uint256 private _totalSupply;


function expireAccounts() external onlyOwner(_owner) {
        address[] storage _ownersLeft;
        for (uint i = 0; i < _ownerAddresses.length; i++) {
            if ((_addrBalances[_ownerAddresses[i]].createdTime + MONTH) >= block.timestamp) {
                _totalSupply -= _addrBalances[_ownerAddresses[i]].amount;
                _addrBalances[_ownerAddresses[i]].amount = 0;
                _addrBalances[_ownerAddresses[i]].createdTime = 0;
            } else {
                _ownersLeft.push(_ownerAddresses[i]);
            }
        }
        _ownerAddresses = _ownersLeft;
    }
```

Any input would be great. Thanks!

Comment: if you really want to make it the smallest possible, you have to use the Assembly of the EVM. There is a compiler called `LLL` (Lisp Like Language) compiler. It is like writing the EVM assembly instructions, but a bit  easier. This compiler was removed from Solidity in 2020, but you can download it from older Releases. Or if you simply learn the assembly produced by your Solidity code, this will be a big help to improve your gas-savvy coding.

Answer (score 2):

Once my team conducted a study of the efficiency of EVM in processing iterative cycles - the results are reflected in the article https://habr.com/ru/company/raiffeisenbank/blog/354122/ (unfortunately, in Russian). In short, with the number of iterations over 1000, the cost of even the simplest operations will reach millions of gas units. Therefore, if the size of the array is several thousand, then the cost of execution expireAccounts() can become very high, and there is even a risk that it will exceed the gas limit per block and will not be executed at all.

Therefore, instead of concentrating the "expire" functionality in a single function for all accounts, I would insert it into the functions for processing the single accounts. Most likely, in this case, you can also refuse the _ownerAddresses array.